# Activity stack management. How to avoid duplicates?

Tags: android, performance

So in my app I have multiple activities and fragments. The user will typically "browse" back and forth using the navigation menu. My problem is that this leads to multiple instances of the same activity in the back stack and seemingly unnecessarily high memory usage.

Consider the following:

1. User starts app. Main activity is shown.
2. User goes to Activity B
3. User goes to Activity C
4. User goes to Activity B again using the navigation menu.

When the user hits the back button he will be brought back to Activity C, then activity B again and finally back to the main activity.

I'm trying to figure out how to best manage this. I've seen several suggestions but I've yet to find consensus on what the best solution might be.

Thanks all!

Comment: I think you should change your some structure of your application. By creating a A Activity having navigation drawer, and on navigation drawer item click you have to change fragments B, C and so on.

Comment: to avoid multiple instances of SameActivity you can declare in the Manifest the Activity as `android:launchMode="singleTask"`. This will create only 1 instance and everytime the same Activity will be opened